# Heat balance of the ISS: breakdown?

Tags: iss, heat

Is there available breakdown of the heat balance of the International Space Station?

In particular:

- *How much heat is produced?*

  - by direct warming by sun
  - by warming of solar panels (heat for the sake of energy production)
  - by life support systems
  - by present humans
- *How much heat is radiated away?*

  - via active cooling (heat radiators)
  - through other surfaces

The mentioned categories are just examples what I understand under the breakdown, a breakdown into different categories will also be very interesting.

Comment: Heat production by direct warming by sun and by presence of astronauts will not be constant over time.

Comment: Yes, I know it is necessarily a simplification. But maybe breakdown for average situation would be available, or it would be possible to obtain ranges for some of these?

Comment: Are you talking about the interior of the ISS (the habitable volume) or something else?

Comment: Yes, about the pressurized habitable volume.

Comment: Heat produced by warming of solar panels is conducted to the pressurized habitable volume only in a very, very small amount.

Answer (score 3):

On the US Operating System side:

The External Active Thermal Control System has two independent loops, each of which can reject up to 35 kW, for a total of 70 kW.

[image]

> The EATCS provides heat rejection capabilities for all U.S.
>   pressurized modules and the main power distribution electronics on S0,
>   S1 and P1.

Additionally there are 4 PhotoVoltaic Radiators (PVRs) which cool the solar array power generation systems.  Each PVR can reject up to 14 kW.

[image]

Total heat loads must remain less than the capabilities of these loops in order to control the internal temperature.

[Source](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/473486main_iss_atcs_overview.pdf)